Setting default programs for only one file in Windows
I will explain my problem through an example. I have three PDF files (A.pdf, B.pdf, C.pdf) with Chrome set as the default program to open them all. Now, I want to configure it so that file A opens with Firefox, while files B and C still open with Chrome.
On the other hand, I want these changes to be permanent. Meaning from now on, file A will open with Firefox and the others will open with, for example, Chrome.
So : I am looking for a solution other than "Open With" to make these changes permanent. Since in this solution the changes are not permanent and it only opens the file with that specific program once.
Well, what is the solution to my problem ?!

@JayCravens That is actually a pretty good idea. Why don't you write that out as an answer so you can earn reputation with it too, and help others finding that answer?

@LPChip No problem. Added.

You could make your own extension.
Rename it to a type that is not assigned, like .pdff, and then set the "Open With..." to use the default application of your choice.
As @KJ says above:

"...I think that is the simplest and best method I changed one to FFD for FireFoxDocument and now any FFD will show FFlogo and Opens With "Always" launches FireFoxPortable".


Great answer! :) +1

The simplest solution would be to open the file A.pdf using a batch
script (.bat) which will look like this:
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" \path\to\A.pdf

A (much) more complex solution would be to isolate the files such as
A.pdf in a separate folder.
Then install the free and open-source
Sandboxie
and create a sandbox where Firefox is defined in the registry
as the handler for PDF files, with the restriction that this sandbox
includes only that folder.
